# php folder structure XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, parent, directory

Using PHP (XAMPP)

I have a simple folder layout as such:

[image: Folder Layout]

For right now, my index.php file just contains "mainbar.php"

mainbar.php:

```
<?php
  require(config.php);
  include ("login/session.php");
  global $session;
  $logged=$session->CheckSession();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/mainbar.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<section class='topcontainer'>
  <nav id='mainnav'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' class='acti' id='homepage'>Home<span class='badge red'>3</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='qms/qms.php' id='qmspage'>QMS<span class='badge yellow'>35</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#' id='modelpage'>Model Search</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' id='partsdbpage'>Parts Database</a></li>      
      <li><a href='#' id='wddbpage'>WD Database</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' id='toolspage'>Tools</a></li>
      <li><img src='styles/img/profile.png' width='25px'/></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

When the user clicks on the "QMS" button (href='qms/qms.php').

I get the following error (using chrome):

```
Failed to load resource (http://localhost/control/qms/scripts/jquery.js)
```

PHP is going to the directory "qms" and then trying to find the "scripts" folder which I do not want it to do.

Keep in mind I just can't make it say "../scripts/jquery.js" because that may not always be the case.

How do I set this up so that "jquery.js" will have a permanent reference back to the parent folder "control/scripts/"??

Answer (score 1):

you can just do as :

`<script src='http://localhost/control/scripts/jquery.js'></script>`

or use some global variable for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Amit suggests using the absolute path, but this is inflexible. You'll have to change the paths of these when you deploy the site, and if you ever change the name of your localhost, you'll have to manually update everything.

I'm assuming that your site's configured to use the root directory of `localhost/controls`. If this is the case, you should be able to link to the script from anywhere in the controls folder using "/scripts/jquery.js".

To find your root directory, run this in a PHP script: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Actually my root directory is:  C:/xampp/htdocs. Should I set it to: C:/xampp/htdocs/controls?

Comment: If control is the only site you're running on your XAMPP installation, that won't be a problem. If it isn't, however, I'd look into virtualhosts to separate concerns and to let you set site-specific root directories: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/ is a good XAMPP-specific guide. It also makes accessing projects easier and more memorable; for example, the two current dev projects I'm working on are accessed via "atwd.dev" and "dmp.dev" instead of localhost/atwd and localhost/dmp. Hope this helps!

Comment: I set the directory as my document_root and it does reference the file HOWEVER, it says "NOT ALLOWED TO LOAD LOCAL RESOURCE" (using chrome). How do I allow it to load local resource?